# How To post Double Quote String in Json to webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am trying to post json which have sub string with double quotes using backslash `\` After post below mentioned json I am expecting `DataFilter="RoleName="Rakesh"` but 
    I am getting `DataFilter="RoleName=\"Rakesh\"`

```
    {
    "DataFilter":"RoleName=\"Rakesh\" " 
    }
```

Is there any way to get string with double double quotes

Comment: You said you want double double quotes so "RoleName="Rakesh"", I would add another escape so it would be `"RoleName=\"Rakesh\"\"". That, or you can use character entities: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref so it would be `"RoleName=&quot;Rakesh&quot"` I haven't tested that so it may not work. Just a suggestion.

Comment: But this is deserialized in "RoleName=\"Rakesh\"\" " but I am expecting DataFilter="RoleName="Rakesh""